# Sending preflight cors request in javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, http-headers, cors

I'm trying to send POST request to the custom api (which i have credentials for) but keep getting 401 error "Unathorized". This is part of code that makes request:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var test = [{
                          "action": "start",
                          "time": "2014-05-02T13:09:22+02:00",
                          "channel": {
                          "id": "rtvslo1"
                          },
                          "content": {
                            "id": "rtvslo1",
                             "title": "testContent",
                             "channel_id": "rtvslo1",
                             "time": "2014-05-02T13:09:22+02:00",
                             "duration": 3
                          },
                          "subscriber": {
                            "id": "f8721ca0-d1e9-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66",
                            "country": "si"
                          },
                          "device": {
                            "id": "012fa920-d1ea-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66",
                            "type": "tv"
                          },
                          "hd": false,
                          "test": true
                        }];

            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(test);

            httpRequest.open('POST', url, true);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpRequest.send(jsonString);
```

When im trying to see error in chrome dev tools i get that **OPTIONS** request was 401 Unathorized, so it doesnt even get to the POST.

In chrom dev tools i get output: Name: events Method:OPTIONS status 401...

OPTIONS http://xstreampipy.tvbeat.com/api/2.0/events 401 (Unauthorized)myFunction @ test.html:39onclick @ test.html:60
test.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xstreampipy.tvbeat.com/api/2.0/events. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Any help would be appreciated :)!

Comment: Does the API allow "OPTIONS" to be sent? Also, an `OPTIONS` pre flight request only gets sense when the `content-type` is `application/json`. Will your AP acceptI the request if the content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: API is predefined to accept json format, and i dont know if it is allowed to send OPTIONS, the API isnt configured by me so i cant tell you exactly (or maybe i can read it in dev tools headers?).

Comment: You should co-ordinate with your API developer. If the API is not accepting a POST request because the pre-flight OPTIONS request is being rejected by the server, then there is likely server-side work needing to be done to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the rest request you are making is cross domain i.e mydomain.com --> restservicedomain.com. These requests are no longer valid or depricated(don't know why they will do that). There are many ways to workaround this problem. You can use these links to understand and implement a solution -

- https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/
- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

I am also still trying to implement a CORS request so don't have a running code.